# Neo4jclient Unwind resulting in Pascal case property names only with Bolt protocol

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Using Neo4j.Driver.Signed.1.7.2 and Neo4jClient.3.1.0.6, we are trying to generate a cypher query that unwinds a collection and use the results in a node create statement. When using the http protocol the property name in the unwind is in camel case in the database, as expected. With the Bolt protocol the property is in Pascal case in the database. In the example, we expect the property name to be 'polarity', but it creates 'Polarity'. This is causing issues with matching properties on subsequent queries. The issue appears to be occurring after the query text is created as it is correctly cased in the Query Debug text in both cases. Something happens that alters the property name in the unwind to Pascal case when sending the query in a Bolt payload.

```
ICypherFluentQuery query = this.dbContext.Cypher
                .Unwind(infons, infon")
                .With("infon")
                .Create($"(gteInfon:{typeof(GteInfon).Name})")
                .Set("gteInfon = infon");

Query Debug text:
UNWIND [
  {
    "polarity": "Affirmative"
  },
  {
    "polarity": "Negative"
  }
] AS infon
WITH infon
CREATE (gteInfon: GteInfon)
SET gteInfon = infon
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the serializer in the client, though why it's doing that I'm not sure.
If you can write a simple test and put the code into a Bug report on the client's github:

https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/

Then I can look at it - of course - when you're doing that - you could see about fixing it?